# Filter Pandas Dataframe by number of list entries and rearrange output by pairs

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm working with a csv file in the format like the below created by using df.groupby to filter which ids where publicly sharing which links.

```
 url        id
 bbc.com     ['183','194','101']
 cnn.com     ['182', '193', '103']
 google.com  ['131']
```

I'm now trying to turn this into a new csv that shows every time two ids shared the same link.

So my ideal output would look like this, specifically without the quotation marks:

```
source target
183, 194
183, 101
194, 101
182, 193
182, 103
103, 193
```

I would really appreciate any help!

I've tried by starting with df.drop to remove rows that contain less one entry but it reads the whole entry as a string, i.e. ['183, '194', '101'] as a whole string rather than a list so I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use  itertools.combinations(x, k).  Here is example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'url': ['bbc.com', 'cnn.com', 'google.com'],
              'id' : [['183','194','101'], ['182', '193', '103'], ['131']  ]})

df

    url         id
0   bbc.com     [183, 194, 101]
1   cnn.com     [182, 193, 103]
2   google.com  [131]
```

Here is the loop that produces the output:

```
k =2
for x in df['id'].values:
    for a, b in itertools.combinations(x, k):
          print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
 183 194
 183 101
 194 101
 182 193
 182 103
 193 103
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! This worked very well. I realised the problem I had initially was that this crashed with exit code -9. After looking that up it appears to mean the system has run out of memory. 

So I'm now working on a way to split the process into chunks as this code works fine on smaller data sets.